# How to access the body from a request Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I tried to do a Postman request to this endpoint http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/login
with this body:

{
"username" : "Sebastiansantander",
"password" : "1233342"

}

I tried using params.permit[:username,:password]
but the problem is that I cant use them.

how can I access to that parameters in order to use them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little different syntax to achieve that `params.permit(:username, password)`
and then in your code `params[:username]`